# getting a failed and type error when runing "npm run build" from a webpack 5 file. I pasted the code below

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

gregmcnally@Gregs-MacBook-Pro CS55.13-todo-app-week-8-main % npm run build

> todo-app-week08@0.1.0 build /Users/gregmcnally/Downloads/CS55.13-todo-app-week-8-main
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /Users/gregmcnally/Downloads/CS55.13-todo-app-week-8-main/.env.local
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
Failed to compile.

./pages/ssr-no-token.tsx:62:51
Type error: Argument of type 'IncomingMessage & { cookies: NextApiRequestCookies; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
Type 'IncomingMessage & { cookies: NextApiRequestCookies; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.

60 |   // `withAuthUserTokenSSR`.
61 |   const token = await AuthUser.getIdToken()

> 62 |   const endpoint = getAbsoluteURL('/api/example', req)
> |                                                   ^
> 63 |   const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
> 64 |     method: 'GET',
> 65 |     headers: {
> info  - Checking validity of types .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! todo-app-week08@0.1.0 build: `next build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the todo-app-week08@0.1.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gregmcnally/.npm/_logs/2021-12-17T02_08_03_370Z-debug.log
gregmcnally@Gregs-MacBook-Pro CS55.13-todo-app-week-8-main %